# How do I call a .NET webmethod?

Tags: java, android, .net, soap, dataset

Firstly thank you for all answers, this subject may be closed because I made what I want already. I mentioned about how to call a .NET webmethod below.

http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-ile-dataset-donen-bir-net.html

Comment: If you can give up using DataTable and use your own objects and collections I can send you a sample for calling webMethod and using json

Comment: What about `KusmanCustomAdapter`? Does it populate data?

Comment: @breceivemail not really, I need to call this webmethod :( I know what you mean and I use it when I create webservice but this time I have to use this way.

Comment: @kisp KusmanCustomAdapter.DataTable I can send a datatable but in .Net side it has 0 row. How do I send datatable with rows?

Comment: here is a tutorial: http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-ile-dataset-donen-bir-net.html

Comment: If your question was answered, why delete the question? Now no one can go back and see your full question.

Comment: bro, the important thing stays on the topic and frankly i have to say that my question was really silly. I can remove the subject if you want. no problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a method for calling a webservice method, use this:

```
public static SoapPrimitive callWebServiceMethod(String url,
            String namespace, String methodName,
            HashMap<String, Object> parameters, String soapAction)
            throws IOException, XmlPullParserException, SoapFault {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);

        if (parameters != null) {
            String[] keys = new String[0];
            keys = (String[]) parameters.keySet().toArray(keys);
            Object[] vals = (Object[]) parameters.values().toArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
                request.addProperty(keys[i], vals[i]);
            }
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,
                60 * 1000);

        androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
        return (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    }
```

and in your activity:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "MethodName";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/MethodName";

        String url = "http://...";

        HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("param1", param1);
        parameters.put("param2", param2);
        //...

        SoapPrimitive response = callWebServiceMethod(url,
                NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAM, parameters,
                SOAP_ACTION);

        String webServiceResult = response.toString();
```

Comment: this is not what I want to do. I need to make my own soap envelope structure. I can not send a dataset with this way bro.